# cannot convert Vector to DataFrame in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a vector `a = [1,2,3]`.
I want to convert it into a `DataFrame` with

```
convert(DataFrame, a)
```

but this throws a `MethodError`:

```
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Int64,1} to an object of type DataFrame
```

The command

```
convert(DataFrame, a')
```

works, but I actually want a 3×1 column vector.

Is there any other method that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write:

```
julia> DataFrame(a=a)
3×1 DataFrame
 Row │ a
     │ Int64
─────┼───────
   1 │     1
   2 │     2
   3 │     3
```

to give the column name `:a`.